# How to convert this equation to closed form (regular and weighted linear regession)

Tags: closed-form

I have read that the matrix form for the following summation

$$
Error(w) = \sum_{i=0}^{m} w^{T}x_i - y_i
$$

- $w^T$ is the transpose of weights vector in linear regression
- $x_i$ is the ith input in vector x
- and $y_i$ is the ith element of vector y.

is as follows:

$$
(Xw - y)^T (Xw-y)
$$

But I need to know the step-wise matrix algebra to achieve this. Is anybody can help me to understand this rewrite? It seems somehow complicated to me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Should it be $Error(w) = \sum_{i=0}^{m} (W^{T}_i x_i - y_i)^2$?

Comment: Thanks KittyL. W is the vector of coefficients for of $x_1$ and $x_2$ and etc. So, I changed it to lower case. It is not a matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your $w$ is. Since you mentioned linear regression, let's say the line is $y=ax+b$, and the data set is $\{(x_1,y_1),...(x_n,y_n)\}$. Then the equations are:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
x_1&1\\
x_2&1\\
...\\
x_n&1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
b\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
...\\
y_n\end{pmatrix}$$

If this is your $X\vec{w}=\vec{y}$, then the error is the 2-norm of $X\vec{w}-\vec{y}$. In matrix form, the 2 norm of a vector $\vec{u}$ is $\vec{u}^T\vec{u}$, in this case then, $(X\vec{w}-\vec{y})^T(X\vec{w}-\vec{y})$. In equation form though, it is the sum of square of each component, so

$$\sum_{i=0}^{m} ((ax_i+b_i)-y_i)^2=\sum_{i=0}^{m}(\vec{X}_i^T\vec{w}-y_i)^2=\sum_{i=0}^{m}(\vec{w}^T\vec{X}_i-y_i)^2$$

where $\vec{X}_i=\begin{pmatrix}
x_i\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$.

If we weights on the squared error terms, the error becomes

$$\sum_{i=0}^{m} u_i(\vec{w}^{T}\vec{X}_i - y_i)^2$$

The matrix form is

$$(Xw-y)^TU(Xw-y)=[\begin{pmatrix}
x_1&1\\
x_2&1\\
...\\
x_n&1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
b\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
...\\
y_n\end{pmatrix}]^T 
\begin{pmatrix}
u_1 & 0&...&0\\
0&u_2&...&0\\
...&...&...&...\\
0&...&0&u_n
\end{pmatrix}
[\begin{pmatrix}
x_1&1\\
x_2&1\\
...\\
x_n&1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
b\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
...\\
y_n\end{pmatrix}]\\
=[(ax_1+b-y_1), ..., (ax_n+b-y_n)]\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
u_1 & 0&...&0\\
0&u_2&...&0\\
...&...&...&...\\
0&...&0&u_n
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
ax_1+b-y_1\\
...\\
ax_n+b-y_n\end{pmatrix}\\
=[u_1(ax_1+b-y_1), ..., u_n(ax_n+b-y_n)]\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
ax_1+b-y_1\\
...\\
ax_n+b-y_n\end{pmatrix}\\
=\sum_{i=0}^{m} u_i(ax_i+b - y_i)^2\\
=\sum_{i=0}^{m} u_i(\vec{w}^{T}\vec{X}_i - y_i)^2.$$

Comment: When you add weights on $X$, do you mean the data would be $\{(u_1x_1,y_1),..., (u_nx_n,y_n)\}$? If that's the case, you should not write it as $UX$. If you look at the matrix equation, the $u$'s would just appear on the $x$'s, whereas the $1$'s stay the same. I don't think it could be simplified any more.

Comment: Thanks indeed, KittyL. I think your norm 2 explanation was exactly what I didn't know. Now for my own practice purposes, I want to obtain the closed form error formula for weighted linear regression. I think we need to multiply it by U which is a m by m diagonal matrix representing the weight of each $X_i$. And the 2-norm will be $(UXw - y)^T (UXw-y)$. Am I in the right path? Is there any way to expand/ simplify further? Thanks again.

Comment: If you multiply by a diagonal matrix U that way, you will have u also on the $1$'s. The equations become $y_i=a u_i x_i+b u_i$. Is that what you want? If not, you should just change your matrix $X$ to include the u in its first column.

Comment: Yes, I think the right way is multiplying U on all components. since the non-closed formula for weighted regression is: $
Error(w) = \sum_{i=0}^{m} u_i(w^{T}x_i - y_i)$. I found the closed form error function is $(Xw - y)^T U (Xw-y)$. But the one that I have is $(UXw - y)^T (UXw-y)$. I am not sure if both of these equations are the same. What do you think? Is it possible to simplify mine and get into the right one?

Comment: I see. So the weight is on each component of the squared error. The one you have is not the same then. What they have is $\sum_{i=0}^{m} u_i(w^{T}x_i - y_i)^2$. I don't think yours is correct.

Comment: So how do we get from $\sum_{i=0}^{m}u_i(\vec{w}^T\vec{X}_i-y_i)^2$ to $(Xw-y)^TU(Xw-y)$?

Comment: I edited the answer to show that.